# git 1.7.3 using windonws + putty + ssh problem

Tags: ssh, git, putty

I am following [this guide](http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/) however on installing git 1.7.3 there is no installation screen available for me to choose `plink.exe` as my ssh execuitable.

As according to [this post](http://www.mail-archive.com/msysgit@googlegroups.com/msg00269.html) I have added a `GIT_SSH` enviromental variable pointing where my `plink.exe` is.

I followed the guide and used puttygen.exe to generate by private and public key and placed my public key on to our projectlockers website. I also saved my private key. I also loaded up my private key into pagent.exe.

I then tried using git clone to get the project using ssh but it unfortunately asked for a password, indicating that the ssh auth. had not worked.

Have I linked up git correctly with my public and private ssh keys?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: It should work !!! check whether plink.exe is in your system path or not.

Comment: echo $GIT_SSH$ C:\Program Files\Putty\plink.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just run into this trouble last night and the solution that worked for me was:

- Putty has to be installed before Git
- Putty needs at least one session created and saved (it will not work without that)
- Install Git again and the screen for selecting the ssh client (Openssh or Plink) should appear.

Comment: It has been a long time since this post, I did manage to get it working in the end and I did something similar to what you described.